# Hiding a dropdown when there's a click outside of it (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, drop-down-menu

I am using this code to hide a dropdown when I click outside of it:

```
$('body').click(function() {
    $('#ddbox').hide();
});

$('#ddbox').click(function(event){
      event.stopPropagation();
});
```

It's working. However, I have another link that shows/hides this dropdown. And when I use the above code, I need to click on that link twice for the dropdown to appear. This is the show/hide code for the dropdown:

```
$('#ddtrigger').toggle(function() {
     $('#ddbox').show();
}, function() {
     $('#ddbox').hide();
});
```

What could be the problem?

**EDIT (this is the HTML):**

```
<a href="#" id="ddtrigger">Some link</a>

<div id="ddbox">

    <p>Some text</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's `.toggle` problem. You have 2 links. So those toggle functions for those 2 are not synced. Why don't u change `.toggle` into something like this.

```
$('#ddtrigger').click(function() {
     $('#ddbox').toggle();
});
```

Comment: When I use "click", the dropdown doesn't appear at all.

Comment: I edited my question w/ HTML. The HTML is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the jquery blur event on the dropdown to hide it?

Answer (score 0):

may be you will find this usefull...

```
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    if($( e.target ).parent( 'Object_to_hide' ).length == 0 ) {
        Object_to_hide.hide();
    }
});
```

i once used this and it worked great...